# Set Manual Proxy in wcf basicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, data-binding

Below is my code for setting user specified proxy address.

```
  private Binding GetBinding()
   {
     BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BINDING_CONFIG_NAME);
     basicHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
     basicHttpBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
     basicHttpBinding.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://10.222.22.22:3988");
     return basicHttpBinding;
   }
```

I keep getting wrong Uri format error. What could be the right way to set Manual Proxy Address ? 
And, It's working fine if I test with Default IE Proxy Settings. Thanks.

Edit : below is the code for setting endpoint.

```
 ApptServiceClient client = new ApptServiceClient
            (GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(this.Uri));
            client.Open();
```

Comment: When exactly you are getting it ? Also can you post the part where you are setting endpoint.

Comment: and where you are getting exception ?

Comment: Finally, i found out that it's the problem from proxy server side. My code is working fine.Sorry to trouble. Thank you.

Comment: You can close the question then?